# Google Apps domain authentication for wordpress projects

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I want to lock down a wordpress (PHP) project on GAE to be accessible only to domain users. I set up my app.yaml so all routes are `login: required` or `login: admin` , and in the appengine.google.com console, set it to use the "Google Apps domain" authentication type.

At first, it worked. However, now even if you are signed in to the domain, it behaves as if you are not authorized (returns error 500). I suspect that the difference is the instance was already warmed up the first time, whereas the second time, it was not.

Any way around this / has anyone experienced this problem and found a solution?

Comment: 500 is Internal Server Error, not permission denied. Do you see anything in your log?

Comment: Nothing in the log. Error occurs before request even hits the app. I think you get error 500 if you are not authorized for a Google App, maybe for security reasons.

I just tried it again, and can confirm: when the instance is cold, setting it to use Google Apps domain authentication results in error 500. When it is warmed up, it works fine.

Comment: I just found [this about warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Warmup_Requests), when I have a sec I will try it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Setting warmup requests doesn't help. I have max idle instances and max pending latency set, and get the same error.